# What happens if you are holding an Iron Flask with a demon inside and walk into an Antimagic Field?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, antimagic-field

What happens if you are holding an [Iron Flask](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/iron-flask) with a demon inside and walk into an Antimagic Field?

Do the magical powers of the Iron Flask stop, releasing the demon? Also, would the demon then be sent back to its original plane (the Abyss)?

Comment: Jester, are you a player (looking for what to expect if you try it with your character) or a DM (looking for how to rule if a player tries it)? For a question like this, it might affect how people try to answer your question.

Comment: @Jester When you feel that an answer has solved your problem and is the best or most correct, you can press the check mark next to the answer to mark it as your "accepted answer." Often we recommend people wait a little while before accepting an answer if it's a tricky or contentious problem; your problem isn't clear cut, so you might want to wait a day or so to see if any competing answers are posted. Otherwise, which answer you accept (if any) is entirely up to you. If you accept an answer, that person will get extra reputation for it-- that's all the thanks they need.

Comment: Hi Jester, it appears you may have created two accounts. [You can follow these instructions to merge them](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Once you do you'll regain ownership over this question and will be able to vote and accept answers.

Answer (score 30):

## It stays in the flask

A related question:
[What happens to a bag of holding in an Antimagic Field?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92239/what-happens-to-a-bag-of-holding-in-an-antimagic-field)

The iron flask seems to function like a pocket dimension for the captured creature, which is why I'd personally rule that the flask simply turns into a normal flask, and is cut off from the pocket dimension for the duration.

The [*Antimagic Field*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) spell itself seems to confirm this (emphasis mine):

> Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are **suppressed** in the sphere and can't protrude into it. A slot expended to cast a suppressed spell is consumed. While an effect is suppressed, it doesn't function, but the time it spends suppressed counts against its duration.

The word *suppressed* is not the same as *dispelled*. This means its effects simply cannot be used, not that the effects disappear. This is especially true if you look at the last sentence, which specifically states that any spell cast is "active", it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Note that the "related question" is about Pathfinder 1e, not D&D 5e.

Answer (score 12):

I'm breaking it down into parts, for clarity.

> Do the magical powers of the Iron Flask stop

Yes, that's what Antimagic field does; it stops items from functioning.

> releasing the demon?

This is unclear and depends on how exactly your Iron Flask works. Since the demon probably doesn't *actually* fit inside the flask, it must either be magically reduced in size to fit *or* be banished to an extradimensional space linked to the flask.

Given that you need to cast Identify to find out if anything is inside the flask, it sounds most logical to me that the creature isn't actually in the flask, but is in a separate dimension. Otherwise, you'd be able to determine if anything was in the flask pretty easily by shaking it.

In that case, it's likely the demon would *not* be released. And, since returning the demon is part of the magic of unstoppering the flask, likely it would not even come out of the flask if you pulled the stopper while in the anti-magic field.

If you instead decide that the creature is physically in the flask and being shrunk by it, then stepping into an anti-magic field would break the containment & shrink effects, and it would grow back too full size while inside the flask. This would probably destroy the flask *or* kill the creature.

> Also, would the demon then be sent back to its original plane (the Abyss)?

No, nothing about the flask says anything about returning contents to their original plane, and the demon coming from the flask isn't a summoned creature. So the demon would simply remain wherever it appeared. This is also what happens normally, when you release the creature. Unless it has some means of moving itself between planes, it remains trapped where it is.

**final note**

*if* you rule that the creature is released when you step into the anti-magic field, or otherwise release the creature *before* stepping into the anti-magic field, do keep in mind that the Anti-magic field will also suppress the part of the Iron Flask that makes the creature friendly to you. So you'll probably have a pretty angry demon to deal with in that situation.

Comment: This answer gave me an idea: you put the demon inside the flask, step into antimagic field, open the flask and put your cookies inside. Nobody would be looking for them inside, right?

Comment: Now I can't get the image of ground-beef style demon rope spewing from the flask when you step into the field: *dangit, lost another one! I really gotta remember to be more careful...*

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go with the opposite answer to the others and say:

## It is forced out of the flask

Other answers assume that the flask works merely as a gate to an extradimensional storage space. While not an unreasonable one, it is still a GM ruling, as nowhere in the description of the [Iron Flask](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/iron-flask) does it say so. Instead, it says:

> the target must succeed on a DC 17 Wisdom saving throw or be trapped **in the flask.**

and

> Once trapped, a creature remains **in the flask** until released.

and also

> You can use an action to remove the flask's stopper and release the creature **the flask contains**.

Taken literally, this shows that the creature **actually goes inside the flask**. Therefore the magic that holds it inside is suppressed when in the Antimagic Field.

Comment: Isn't "until released" referencing the action to unstopper it?

Comment: @NautArch Yes, but that's not the part of the quotes I'm referencing, I edited for clarity

Comment: Sure, but it seems like the action to release it is stopper removal. It doesn't say anything about other release methods.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I see it as "the AM field suppresses the magical effect that holds the demon in the flask", which means that the demon is no longer held in the flask